# Get the values on type in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, controller

I have 2 textboxes..

- Email
- Mobile Number

I check the 2 fields with database by link using `JQuery`. When I enter the values in the textbox, it should automatically check the value and show a popup saying 'already registered' and also get the related values..

**My code is**

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
                $('#getCandidate').text('Get Profile') // Sets text for email.
                    .attr('href', '#');

                $("#getCandidate").click(function () {

                    $('#getCandidate').text('Get Profile') 
                    .attr('href', 'GetCandidateDetail?validateEmail=' + $('#Email').val());
                });

                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('#checkEmail').click(function () {
                        var name = $('#Email').val();
                        var data = 'validateEmail=' + name;
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            url: "ValidateCandidate",
                            data: data,
                            success: function (data) {
                                   alert(data);

                            }
                        });
                        return false;
                    });
                });
          </script>
```

**Controller:**

```
 public ActionResult GetCandidateDetail(string validateEmail, string validateMobile)
    {

        Candidate candidate = null;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(validateEmail))
        {
            candidate = _userRepository.GetCandidateByEmail(validateEmail);
            if (candidate == null)
               candidate = new Candidate();
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(validateMobile))
        {
            candidate = _userRepository.GetCandidateByMobileNumber(validateMobile);
            if (candidate == null)
                candidate = new Candidate();
        }
        else
        {
            if (candidate == null)
                candidate = new Candidate();
        }
...
```

How to automatically check in `JQuery`, without clicking the link. I tried the `blur function` but in vain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  `trigger` the `chekEmail` link on `change` or `blur` depends on your need

```
$('#Email').blur(function() {
    $('#checkEmail').trigger('click'); //it will trigger the link when the text losses focus
});

OR

$('#Email').change(function() {
    $('#checkEmail').trigger('click');  //it will trigger the link each time when the text gets changed 
});
```

Comment: it is working good for me. But when the alert message come automatically it should getcandidatedetails.. How to do this?

Comment: where you want to display the candidate details?

Comment: In page only..i want to just pass the GetCandidateDetails inside the jquery when click ok. all other methods are i developed in controller. i don't know jquery. that's why struggling..